# SQL Server Service Broker - Ways to improve SQL execution framework

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, etl, service-broker

Below is an outline of a SQL execution framework design using `Service Broker` that I have been playing with. I've outlined the process and have asked some questions through (highlight using a block quote) and would be interested in hearing any advice on the design.

### Overview

I have a an ETL operation that needs to take data out of 5 databases and move it into 150 using `select/insert` statements or `stored procedures`. The result is about 2,000 individual queries, taking between 1 second to 1 hour each.

Each SQL query inserts data only. There is no need for data to be returned.

The operation can be broken up into 3 steps:

- Pre-ETL
- ETL
- Post-ETL

The queries in each step can be executed in any order, but the steps have to stay in order.

### Method

I am using `Service Broker` for asynchronous/parallel execution.

> Any advice on how to tune service broker (e.g. any specific options to look at or guide for setting the number of queue workers?

#### Service Broker Design

Initiator

The `initiator` sends an `XML` message containing the SQL query to the `Unprocessed` queue, with an activation stored procedure called `ProcessUnprocessedQueue`. This process is wrapped in a `try/catch` in a transaction, rolling back the transaction when there is an exception.

ProcessUnpressedQueue

`ProcessUnprocessedQueue` passes the XML to procedure `ExecSql`

ExecSql - SQL Execution and Logging

`ExecSql` then handles the SQL execution and logging:

- The `XML` is parsed, along with any other data about the execution that is going to be logged
- Before the execution, a logging entry is inserted

  - > If the transaction is started in the `initiator`, can I ensure the log entry insert is always committed if the outer transaction in the `initiator` is rolled back?
  - > Something like `SAVE TRANSACTION` is not valid here, correct?
  - > Should I *not* manipulate the transaction here, execute the query in a `try/catch` and, if it goes to the catch, insert a log entry for the exception and `throw` the exception since it is in the middle of the transaction?
- The query is executed

Alternative Logging Solution?

I need to log:

- The SQL query executed
- Metadata about the operation
- The time it takes for each process to finish

  - This is why I insert one row at the start and one at the end of the process
- Any exceptions, if they exist

Would it be better to have an `In-Memory OLTP` table that contains the query information? So, I would have `INSERT` a row before the start of an operation and then do an `UPDATE` or `INSERT` to log exceptions and execution times. After the batch is done, I would then archive the data into a table stored to the disk to prevent the table from getting too big.

ProcessUnprocessedQueue - Manually process the results

After the execution, `ProcessUnprocessedQueue` gets back an updated version of the `XML` (to determine if the execution was successful, or other data about the transaction, for post-processing) and then sends that message to the `ProcessedQueue`, which **does not** have an activation procedure, so it can be manually processed (I need to know when a batch of queries has finished executing).

#### Processing the Queries

Since the ETL can be broken out into 3 steps, I create 3 `XML` variables where I will add all of the queries that are needed in the ETL operation, so I will have something like this:

- @preEtlQueue xml

  - 200 queries
- @etlQueue xml

  - 1500 queries
- @postEtlQueue xml

  - 300 queries

Why XML?

> The XML queue variable is passed between different stored procedures as an `OUTPUT` parameter that updates it's values and/or add SQL queries to it. This variable needs to be written and read, so an alternative could be something like a global temp table or a persistent table.

I then process the `XML` variables:

- Use a `cursor` to loop through the queries and send them to the service broker service.

  - Each group of queries contained in the `XML` variable is sent under the same `conversation_group_id`.
  - Values such as the to/from service, message type, etc. are all stored in the `XML` variable.
- After the messages are sent to Service Broker, use a while loop to continuously check the `ProcessedQueue` until all the messages have been processed.

  - This implements a timeout to avoid an infinite loop
  - > I'm thinking of redesigning this. Should I add an activation procedure on `ProcessedQueue` and then have that procedure insert the processed results into a physical table? If I do it this way, I wouldn't be able to use `RECEIVE` instead of a `WHILE` loop to check for processed items. Does that have any disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't built anything as massive as what you are doing now, but I will give you what worked for me, and some general opinions...

- My preference is to avoid In-Memory OLTP and write everything to durable tables and keep the message queue as clean as possible
- Use fastest possible hard drives in the server, write speed equivalent of NVMe or faster with RAID 10 etc.
- I grab every message off the queue as soon as it hits and write it to a table I have named "mqMessagesReceived" (see code below, my all-purpose MQ handler named mqAsyncQueueMessageOnCreate)
- I use a trigger in the "mqMessagesReceived" table that does a lookup to find which StoredProcedure to execute to process each unique message (see code below)
- Each message has an identifier (in my case, I'm using the originating Tablename that wrote a message to the queue) and this identifier is used as a key for a lookup query run inside the the trigger of the mqMessagesReceived table, to figure out which subsequent Stored Procedure needs to be to run, to process each received message correctly.
- Before sending a message on the MQ,

Can make a generic variable from the calling side (e.g. if a trigger is putting messages onto the MQ)

```
SELECT @tThisTableName = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) FROM sys.objects 
WHERE sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
AND SCHEMA_NAME(sys.objects.schema_id) = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID);
```

- A configuration table is the lookup data for matching tablename with StoredProcedure that needs to be run, to process the MQ data that arrived and was written to the mqMessagesReceived table.

Here is the definition of that lookup table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mqMessagesConfig](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [tSourceTableReceived] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [tTriggeredStoredProcedure] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_mqMessagesConfig] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is the activation stored procedure that gets run as a message hits the queue

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mqAsyncQueueMessageOnCreate]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
 
    DECLARE 
        @h UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @t sysname,
        @b varbinary(200),
        @hand VARCHAR(36),
        @body VARCHAR(2000),
        @sqlcleanup nvarchar(MAX)

        
 
    -- Get all of the messages on the queue
    -- the WHILE loop is infinite, until BREAK is received when we get a null handle
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @h = NULL
 
        --Note the semicolon..!
        ;RECEIVE TOP(1) 
            @h = conversation_handle,
            @t = message_type_name,
            @b = message_body
        FROM mqAsyncQueue


        --No message found (handle is now null)
        IF @h IS NULL
        BEGIN
            -- all messages are now processed, but we still have the @hand variable saved from processing the last message
            SET @sqlcleanup = 'EXEC [mqConversationsClearOne]  @handle = N' + char(39) + @hand + char(39) + ';';
            EXECUTE(@sqlcleanup);
            BREAK
        END


        --mqAsyncMessage message type received
        ELSE IF @t = 'mqAsyncMessage'
        BEGIN
            SET @hand = CONVERT(varchar(36),@h);
            SET @body = CONVERT(varchar(2000),@b);
            
            INSERT mqMessagesReceived  (tMessageType, tMessageBody, tMessageBinary, tConversationHandle)
            VALUES (@t, @body, @b, @hand);
        
        END
        
        
        --unknown message type was received that we dont understand
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT mqMessagesReceived (tMessageBody, tMessageBinary)  
            VALUES ('Unknown message type received', CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), 'Unknown message type received'))
        END

    END        

END






CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mqConversationsClearOne]

    @handle varchar(36)

AS

    -- Note: you can check the queue by running this query
    -- SELECT * FROM sys.conversation_endpoints 
    -- SELECT * FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WHERE NOT([State] = 'CO') 
    -- CO = conversing [State]


    DECLARE @getid CURSOR
            ,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@conv_id NVARCHAR(100)
            ,@conv_handle NVARCHAR(100)


    -- want to create a chain of statements like this, one per conversation
    -- END CONVERSATION 'FE851F37-218C-EA11-B698-4CCC6AD00AE9' WITH CLEANUP;
    -- END CONVERSATION 'A4B4F603-208C-EA11-B698-4CCC6AD00AE9' WITH CLEANUP;    

    SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
                    SELECT [conversation_id], [conversation_handle]  
                    FROM   sys.conversation_endpoints
                    WHERE conversation_handle = @handle;


    OPEN @getid

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @getid INTO @conv_id, @conv_handle 
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = 'END CONVERSATION ' + char(39) + @conv_handle + char(39) + ' WITH CLEANUP;'
                EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql;
                FETCH NEXT
                FROM @getid INTO @conv_id, @conv_handle  --, @conv_service
            END

    CLOSE @getid
    DEALLOCATE @getid
```

and the table named "mqMessagesReceived" has this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[mqMessagesReceived_TriggerUpdate]

ON [dbo].[mqMessagesReceived]

AFTER INSERT

AS
  BEGIN


    DECLARE     

    @strMessageBody nvarchar(4000),
    @strSourceTable nvarchar(128),
    @strSourceKey nvarchar(128),
    @strConfigStoredProcedure nvarchar(4000),
    @sqlRunStoredProcedure nvarchar(4000),
    @strErr nvarchar(4000)


    SELECT @strMessageBody= ins.tMessageBody FROM INSERTED ins; 

    SELECT @strSourceTable = (select txt_Value from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(@strMessageBody,'|') WHERE Position=2);

    SELECT @strSourceKey =  (select txt_Value from dbo.fn_ParseText2Table(@strMessageBody,'|') WHERE Position=3);

    
    -- look in mqMessagesConfig to find the name of the final stored procedure 
    -- to run against the SourceTable
    -- e.g.  @strConfigStoredProcedure = mqProcess-tblLabDaySchedEventsMQ

    SELECT @strConfigStoredProcedure =
    (select tTriggeredStoredProcedure from dbo.mqMessagesConfig WHERE tSourceTableReceived = @strSourceTable);

    

    SET @sqlRunStoredProcedure = 'EXEC [' + @strConfigStoredProcedure + ']  @iKey = ' + @strSourceKey + ';';
    EXECUTE(@sqlRunStoredProcedure);


    INSERT INTO [mqMessagesProcessed]
    ( 
        [tMessageBody],
        [tSourceTable],
        [tSourceKey],
        [tTriggerStoredProcedure]
    )

    VALUES  
    (
        @strMessageBody,
        @strSourceTable,
        @strSourceKey,
        @sqlRunStoredProcedure
    );


  END
```

Also, just some general SQL Server tuning advice that I found I also had to do (for dealing with a busy database)

By default there is just one single TempDB file per SQL Server, and TempDB has initial size of 8MB

However TempDB gets reset back to the initial 8MB size, every time the server reboots, and this company was rebooting the server every weekend via cron/taskscheduler.

The problem we saw was slow database and lots of record locks but only first thing Monday morning when everyone was hammering the database at once as they began their work-week.

When TempDB gets automatically re-sized, it is "locked" and therefore nobody at all can use that single TempDB (which is why the SQL Server was regularly becoming non-responsive)

By Friday the TempDB had grown to over 300MB.

So...  to solve the following best practice recommendation, I created one TempDB file per vCPU, so I created 8 TempDB files, and I have distributed them across two available hard drives on that server, and most importantly, set their initial size to more than we need (200MB each is what I chose).

This fixed the problem with the SQL Server slowdown and record locking that was experienced every Monday morning.